# Copyright - television broadcasting with offline storage, not playing same across devices

Tags: copyright, india

I am looking for insight into copyright laws to see if it is legal to do the following:

Party-A runs a television channel and has broadcast rights for movie contents.

Party-B builds video playing infrastructure in public places and invites television channels to participate. Under this plan, the video contents would be stored in the devices and then played.

Let's say Part-A agrees to participate.

If all the devices may not play the same video at a given time, would it be a violation of the rights of original copyright owner of the video (movie content)

If all the devices play the same video at a given time, technically the infrastructure is only a different broadcasting medium for television. In that case, is it still a violation of the copyright laws in any way?

Answer (score 1):

All of this turns on the terms of the licence between A and the copyright holder; without knowing those terms the question is impossible to answer. Specifically, the behaviour contemplated would need to be provided for in the licence.